# Jon Skeet's answer is flagged as Low Quality

Tags: discussion, reputation, low-quality-posts

I was doing a Low Quality post review and came across this:

[image]

The actual question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489173/writing-xml-with-c-sharp) and the link to the review is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6029479).

My question is this: would it make sense to determine a reputation threshold after a user's question or answer doesn't go into the review queue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to consider a user's reputation. Some users do still make mistakes, and they should not be immune from review.

I'm not saying Jon's answer should be in the queue, just that reputation does not mean you don't ever make mistakes, or that the rules of the site haven't changed and an answer is low quality *by today's standards*.

In this case, the *very* old post is [not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer), it is a comment. It was posted not long after the site added the comment feature (September 2008), so perhaps Jon simply forgot to post that as a comment. Either way, it should probably be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

A low quality post is a low quality post.  The standards of what constitutes a low quality post has changed over time - some posts from the old days which were perfectly acceptable then are not so much anymore.

Users from the old days, by nature of being an early adopter on the site, if still active, will naturally have a higher reputation.

This in no way exempts the user from having their material flagged or the need to maintain old material.

I'd have to go dig through chat transcripts but I *do* recall discussions about if one should flag one of Jeff or Joel's old post as 'not an answer'... and the flag was handled and the post was deleted.

It is important that *everyone* is subject to the same standards, lest people decry that some posts are getting ignored because of a double standard (which can cause additional resentment about being 'elitist' (we're not)).  Also consider that these posts are often used by newer users as examples of "well, Jon was able to post this, why can't I post something like it now?"

Old posts by old users serve as examples of what we want the site to be today and tommorow.

Review it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

#### That answer fits the definition of a low quality answer at best that should be a comment at best.

It is making a generalized statement and then asking for a question for more information, sounds like a comment to me. So it should actually have been flagged *Not an Answer* instead.

> Not An Answer: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt
> to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment,
> another question, or deleted altogether.

The [David Morton one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/489205/177800) isn't any better either now that I read through all of them.